Filter function Delivers the Blank cells in the Array as Zeros and Other Blank cells in time formated cells as 12:00
I have tried these two functions to filter the data from the input table to the output table but they still deliver the Blank cells as zero if the criteria is met and the other one delivers them as 12:00 because the input and output cells are formatted as Time cells.
=FILTER(A2:C12,FILTER(E2:K12,E1:K1=TEXT(A17,"dddd"))="Yes")

=FILTER(FILTER(L2:R12,L1:R1=TEXT(A17,"dddd")),(A2:A12=C17))

Thank you for any tip in advance!


Hey, if you have Windows version, have you considered File > Options > Advanced? Or other option from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03 It may be easier to maintain.

I appreciate your sharing for such a great tip but I am worried that I may need to see zero values in other tables too!

Of course. Please see whether the short function I posted would be helpful.

You could try using the following formulas:


• Formula used in cell C17
=FILTER(A2:C12, 
 BYROW((FILTER(E2:K12,TEXT(B17,"dddd")=E1:K1)="Yes")*(A2:C12<>""),LAMBDA(x,OR(x))))


Now, you won't require the LAMBDA() helper function, if you consider Name List column as your base column, this means as long as there is some data in Column A, the Columns A:C will be returned as output, even the other two columns are empty, then:
=FILTER(A2:C12,(FILTER(E2:K12,TEXT(B17,"dddd")=E1:K1)="Yes")*(A2:A12<>""))


• Formula used in cell F17
=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(L2:R12,
 TEXT(B17,"dddd")=L1:R1),XMATCH(INDEX(C17#,,1),A2:A12))


NOTE: Format the Time column as h:mm;; to hide the 0 values, which means if you ever happen to have time as 00:00 it will be hidden completely, this is only a caveat to make you aware of the fact.


I appreciate your tip and the insight tip on the zero thing! On the other hand, I tried to use the same formula for the time column but it gives me an error #N/A, I tried to check for the possible usages of xmatch function but still my effort was in vain, Let me know if you could share the highlighted zones when you used this formula! Thank you in advance!

C17# refers to the output returned from the first formula. also are you asking me to highlight where the formulas are used is that so? Here is the Excel can download to check where it is not working for you, as works on my end! @Abouzid

I am wondering if the Ranges used are the same like when I applied them in my file as I doubled checked them and still I got the error result

I wonder whether creating a general function in Name Manager would be helpful:
For example, in Name Manager, add _hide_zero
= LAMBDA(
    val,
    [_hide_zero],
    LET(
      _hide,
      IF(ISOMITTED(_hide_zero), TRUE, _hide_zero),
      IF(NOT(_hide), val, IF(val, val, ""))))

Then wrap the results =_hide_zero(_result) as needed. By defining the function with workbook scope, you can use it in any sheet. Also, sheets copied to other workbooks will export the function.
